# Fibonacci calculation using memoization in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I tried below code sniped, while i am initializing **mem[]** array out of the method it is taking **1ms** to execute the code but if i am initializing it inside the method it is taking **~16000** ms to execute. I am not able to understand, why?, please help me out.

```
public class FiboMemoization {
    //public static long [] mem = new long[41];
    public static long fibo(int n){
    //  long [] mem = new long[41];
        if(mem[n] == 0){
            if(n <= 1){
                mem[n] = n; 
            }else if(mem[n] != 0)
                mem[n] = mem[n];
            else
                mem[n] = fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2);
        }
        return mem[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that recursion causes it to initialise *every* time you re-enter the method.

Comment: That's pretty obvious, if you initialize it inside, you create a new (empty) array at each call.

Comment: Yup, there's no C style `static` to have it initialized only once.

Answer (score 1):

It's only memorized if the memory (i.e. `long[] mem`) is stored ***outside*** the function.

`long[] mem` inside the function causes two issues:

1. Reallocates memory every call (slow)
2. Does not do memoization since the array is empty on every function call (new arrays are 0 in Java)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {


    private static int _memo_length;
    private static int _memo_idx;
    private static BigInteger[] _memo;

    static {
        _memo_length = 1024;
        _memo = new BigInteger[_memo_length];
        _memo[0] = BigInteger.ONE;
        _memo[1] = BigInteger.ONE;
        _memo_idx = 1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int xIndex = 4000; //locate the 4000th fibo member.

        BigInteger output = locateFibonacciMember(xIndex - 1);

        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static BigInteger locateFibonacciMember(int idx) {
        if (idx <= _memo_idx) {
            return _memo[idx];
        }
        while (idx > _memo_idx) {
            if (++_memo_idx >= _memo.length) {
                if (!_extendMemo()) return BigInteger.ZERO;
            }
            _memo[_memo_idx] = _memo[_memo_idx - 1].add(_memo[_memo_idx - 2]);
        }
        return _memo[_memo_idx];
    }

    private static boolean _extendMemo() {
        try {
            _memo = Arrays.copyOf(_memo, _memo.length + _memo_length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```